# Can't configure a goal in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have problems configuring a very basic goal in Google Analytics.

My goal page is: https://www.lifeconnections.pe/?action=ff1

I configured the goal as a destination and regular expresion using "/?action=ff1" as the goal text

In Google Analytics the "/?action=ff1" appears as the page visited in the "behavior>site content>all pages" report

Even then, the goal is not being registered.

What can be the error I am making. In Google Analytics documentation can't find the error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use your string value defining contains instead of regex or try to set this value for regex:

```
\/\?action=ff1
```

Comment: But worked both ways so I am duplicating goals, it seems Google need some time to register goals.

Comment: The goal calculation is done again after midnight, however if you use the regex it is better to use the one with escape characters because the '?' is a special character in regex.